# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught MongoDB\Driver\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: Error parsing ObjectId string

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm trying to Query Data from my Database to put the result into the value form an input.
but when I want to fetch the Data, following error is showing up:

> Fatal error: Uncaught MongoDB\Driver\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: Error parsing ObjectId string: 5f4286324becb3f60cbb866e

I really don't know how to solve it, i searched like 2 hours in the WWW.. I hope someone can help me..
Here's my Code:

```
 $id = $_POST['id'];
echo $id;
$client = new MongoDB\Client;
$db = $client->thesis;
$personen = $db->Personen;
$document = $personen->findOne(['_id' => new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId($id)]);
```

I'm getting the ID with the echo but the findOne Method isn't working.

 Thanks for your answers :)
Cheeres

Comment: Make sure that `$id` doesn't contain any spaces or other non-printing characters.  For testing, put `$oid = new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId($id)` after the echo to separate out the conversion to ObjectId from the findOne, so you can be certain which is complaining.